# sort biblatex bibliography by appearance of cites in the document

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm writing my thesis in physics using LateX (MikTeX). For my bibliography i use biblatex with this setup:

```
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex8,                
maxnames=6,                         
bibstyle=numeric,               
hyperref=true,                  
citestyle=authortitle, 
sortcites=true                  
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
```

What I'm trying to do now is to sort the items in the biblography *automatically* by their appearance in the document, i.e. the first cite in the document will be the first item in the bibliography.

I know that biblatex provides several sorting options via

```
sorting=
```

but there isn't an option that fits my sorting order. (I already checked the documentation)

I also know that i could arrange them in my .bib file and choose the option

```
sorting=none
```

but since I got quite a lot of references this is only my last hope.

Is there a way to do that? If so, please tell me. If not, tell me so i can quit searching an start sorting my .bib file.

greetz from germany.

Comment: The way I read the documentation, `sorting=none` does exactly what you want. ('All entries are processed in *citation order*.')

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/PiJ21)

Answer (score 28):

`sorting=none` does what you want. Only if you use `\nocite{*}` and therefore there is no citation order in the document does `biber` use the `.bib` order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me! Don't know why I did not get that.....

Comment: I don't believe that your comment is strictly correct. Sorting=none with nocite{*} means that all of the references which were actually cited appear first in order of appearance, THEN followed by the remaining (non-cited) references contained in the database.

Comment: The main answer in combination with putting biblatex package after hyperref solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my case \nocite{*} was indeed causing entries to be sorted according to their bib file order. This was the case even though every entry was cited.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `\notice{*}` should be removed. But what does `\notice{*}` do? It does not seem to appear in the documentation.

Comment: It's not `\notice` but `\nocite` and `\nocite{*}` simply includes everything in the datasource(s) in the bibliography without citing them.